# Google Bigquery results

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting a part of result from the Bigquery API.
Earlier, I solved the issue of 1,00,000 records per result  using iterators.
However, now I'm stuck at some other obstacle.
If I take more than 6-7 columns in a result, I do not get the complete set of result.
However, if I take a single column, I get the complete result.
Can there be a size limit as well for results in Bigquery API ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some [`limits for Query Job`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs)

In particular

> Maximum response size — 128 MB compressed

Of course, it is unlimited when writing large query results to a destination table (and then reading from there)